# Time required to fill a pipe line

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow

This is quite embarrassing to ask, but I haven't done a fluid flow calculation in a very long time and when you don't use it, you lose it!

I have a natural gas pipeline that I want to purge of air with natural gas.  It's a 3" and 4" line totalling about 6,600 feet.  I'll be injecting natural gas into the line through a 2" hose with a pressure of 15 psi and the outlet will be another 2" hose at the other end.

My question is:
How long will it take to push all of the air out of the pipe and fill it with natural gas (purge the line of air)?

I've spent the last few hours Googling fluid flow questions and answers and just can't figure it out.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's a really complicated question to answer -- if your inlet was the same diameter as your line it would be a little easier but injecting from a smaller pipe will create recirculation regions where gas and air mix. The amount of time it takes for that mixing to result in negligible air left is a very complicated problem to solve.

Comment: Assuming you've got an additive for smell, just smell what comes out the end of the pipe until your nose is satisfied with the quality of natural gas. =)